# VLC Python EventManager callback type?

Tags: python, vlc, libvlc

I'm having trouble attaching an event handler to tell when a song has finished playing when using the VLC Python bindings. The event_attach function is complaining about the callback type.

```
def __init__(self):
    self.vlc = vlc.Instance()
    self.vlc_playlist = self.vlc.media_list_new()
    self.vlc_player = self.vlc.media_list_player_new()
    self.vlc_player.set_media_list(self.vlc_playlist)
    self.vlc_events = self.vlc_player.event_manager()
    self.vlc_events.event_attach(vlc.EventType.MediaPlayerEndReached, self.SongFinished, 1)
    ....
def SongFinished(self, *args, **kwargs):
    pass
```

Errors:

```
self.vlc_events.event_attach(vlc.EventType.MediaPlayerEndReached, self.SongFinished, 1)
return libvlc_event_attach(self, i_event_type, f_callback, user_data)
    ArgumentError: argument 3: <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: wrong type
```

Comment: unfortunately I looked once and didn't see many good tutorials on the python event stuff.  http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&client=safari&pwst=1&rls=en&q=+site:forum.videolan.org+python+vlc+event+attach&sa=X&ei=VO97TLvWL5OqsAPSx7SCBw&ved=0CBsQrQIwAA might help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found it, VLC.py includes a small decorator ctypes function for wrapping callbacks:

`callbackmethod=ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(None, Event, ctypes.c_void_p)`

To use:

```
@callbackmethod
def SongFinished(self, data):
    print data
```

`.event_attach(vlc.EventType.MediaPlayerEndReached, SongFinished, 1)`

Comment: Latest version of vlc.py uses a wrapper so that such decorator is not necessary anymore

Answer (score 16):

Here is basic code for the more recent `vlc.py` using the `event_manager`:

```
import vlc
import time
import sys

finish = 0

def SongFinished(event):
    global finish
    print("\nEvent reports - finished")
    finish = 1

def pos_callback(event, player):
    sec = player.get_time() / 1000
    m, s = divmod(sec, 60)
    npos = event.u.new_position * 100
    sys.stdout.write('\r%s %02d:%02d (%.2f%%)' % ('Position', m, s, npos))
    sys.stdout.flush()

instance = vlc.Instance()
player = instance.media_player_new()
media = instance.media_new_path('vp1.mp3') #Your audio file here
player.set_media(media)
events = player.event_manager()
events.event_attach(vlc.EventType.MediaPlayerEndReached, SongFinished)
events.event_attach(vlc.EventType.MediaPlayerPositionChanged, pos_callback, player)

player.play()
while finish == 0:
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

Note: there are quite a few events for the media player that can be monitored in this way.

```
MediaPlayerMediaChanged
MediaPlayerNothingSpecial
MediaPlayerOpening
MediaPlayerBuffering
MediaPlayerPlaying
MediaPlayerPaused
MediaPlayerStopped
MediaPlayerForward
MediaPlayerBackward
MediaPlayerEndReached
MediaPlayerEncounteredError
MediaPlayerTimeChanged
MediaPlayerPositionChanged
MediaPlayerSeekableChanged
MediaPlayerPausableChanged
MediaPlayerTitleChanged
MediaPlayerSnapshotTaken
MediaPlayerLengthChanged
MediaPlayerVout
MediaPlayerScrambledChanged
MediaPlayerESAdded
MediaPlayerESDeleted
MediaPlayerESSelected
MediaPlayerCorked
MediaPlayerUncorked
MediaPlayerMuted
MediaPlayerUnmuted
MediaPlayerAudioVolume
MediaPlayerAudioDevice
```

For the full current list, search for `class EventType` in the code at
https://github.com/oaubert/python-vlc/blob/master/generated/3.0/vlc.py