# python-vlc doesn't plays and response with the youtube video link?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, youtube, pafy, python-vlc

I have been trying to play the YouTube links from python using `pafy` and `python-vlc`. The code compiles and finishes but the link doesn't play through `vlc` even though I have called `play()` at bottom

I have tried uninstalling the existing `python-vlc` and reinstalling it but the problem persists, I was using sublime text editor for running above code and so I tried this with python IDLE but everything was:

[image]

same

```
import vlc 
import pafy           

url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VwsmkB-YpJo"            
video = pafy.new(url)
best = video.getbest()
playurl = best.url
ins = vlc.Instance()
player = ins.media_player_new()
Media = ins.media_new(playurl)
Media.get_mrl()
player.set_media(Media)
player.play()
```

I expected as an output the video will play but actually it finished up with no any response and errors

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stream youtube audio from python using url without downloading python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49354232/stream-youtube-audio-from-python-using-url-without-downloading-python)

Comment: I have gone through the [above mentioned thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49354232/stream-youtube-audio-from-python-using-url-without-downloading-python) . But my issue is slightly different , everthing is working fine but the video doesn't plays as it should open up a window without controls playing the video of given link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [open url error using vlc in terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46203610/open-url-error-using-vlc-in-terminal) as a starting point I was able to add some debug to see what was going on.
It looks like your python code exits before vlc is running. So I came up with this solution, I have tested it with several different URLs and it seems to work.

```
import vlc
import pafy
import urllib.request

url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9W3A34TTxFU&list=RD9W3A34TTxFU&start_radio=1"
video = pafy.new(url)
best = video.getbest()
playurl = best.url
ins = vlc.Instance()
player = ins.media_player_new()

code = urllib.request.urlopen(url).getcode()
if str(code).startswith('2') or str(code).startswith('3'):
    print('Stream is working')
else:
    print('Stream is dead')

Media = ins.media_new(playurl)
Media.get_mrl()
player.set_media(Media)
player.play()

good_states = ["State.Playing", "State.NothingSpecial", "State.Opening"]
while str(player.get_state()) in good_states:
    print('Stream is working. Current state = {}'.format(player.get_state()))

print('Stream is not working. Current state = {}'.format(player.get_state()))
player.stop()
```

Or you can use events see [VLC Python EventManager callback type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595649/vlc-python-eventmanager-callback-type)

Comment: Thanks a lot ! it worked for me. btw i was using windows os. It worked fine.